# Presto under two package names

Tags: java, presto, trino

I just started developing a Presto connector for JSON API. As suggested in many places, I started with the `example-http` connector and did few changes and deployed the connector as mentioned in the [documentation](https://prestodb.github.io/docs/current/installation/deployment.html). Then I got following error when starting the server.

```
No service providers of type io.prestosql.spi.Plugin
```

Then I noticed the package name for Plugin interface in my code is `com.facebook.presto` and its actually implementing `com.facebook.presto.spi.Plugin` interface.

Have I downloaded a wrong code/distribution? if then, which one is the right one? if not, why two packages?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think you're mixing code from two versions. After the Presto Software Foundation was set up (see announcement: https://prweb.com/releases/prweb16070792.htm), Presto moved to its new home under https://github.org/trinodb/trino and https://trino.io, and all the code was repackaged.

If you have existing code under the old version, see this guide for how to migrate it: https://github.com/trinodb/trino/wiki/Migration

Comment: You are absolutely right sir :D strange thing is that, I wasn't able to find link to new repository through a google search. Thanks a lot for the link and answer.